# Arrays with for loop and if statements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

So when i i have tried to save and compile everything works fine until I run it. There seems to be an issue with my array syntax. Could someone help me find it?When I do run this program the grades()method outputs "AAA" . What I'm trying to do in this program is read text from a txt file and list each line, outputting a student name and score. Now in the grades() method I am trying to output calculate a letter grade for each of the students grades and make that go into a loop until the last score has been read.

```
public class ReadData 
  {
private static String[] names = new String[3];
private static int line;
private static int[] scores = new int[3];
private static float mean;
private static double stdDeviation;

public static void readData() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int l = 0;

    // float sum = 0 ;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] words = line.split("\t"); 
        names[l] = words[0]; 
        scores[l] = Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
        // sum+=scores[l];
        System.out.println(" name: " + names[l] + ", score: " + scores[l]);
        l++; 


    }
   //   System.out.println(scores[0]+ " " + scores[1]+ " " + scores[2]);

}

public static void fndMean() 
{

    float mean = ((25+65+89)/3);
    System.out.println(" The mean is: " + mean);
}


public static void fndStandard() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    double stdDeviation = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(25-59, 2)+(Math.pow(65-59,2))+
            (Math.pow(89-59, 2))))/3);
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation is: " + stdDeviation);
}
```

Grades method

```
public static void grades()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (scores.length); i++)
        {
            if(mean + stdDeviation <= scores[i])
            {
                System.out.print("A");
            }
            else if( (scores[i] >= mean+(stdDeviation/3)) &&  
           (mean     +stdDeviation)> scores[i])
            {
                System.out.print("B");
            }
            else if( (scores[i] >= mean-(stdDeviation/3)) && 
            (mean +(stdDeviation/3))> scores[i])
            {
                System.out.print("C");
            }
            else if( (scores[i] >= mean-(stdDeviation)) &&  
            (mean -            (stdDeviation/3))> scores[i])
            {
                System.out.print("D");
            }   
            else
            {
                System.out.println("F");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: For future readers confused as to where `grades()` is, scroll down.

Comment: Step through your code, it looks like your problem is your assigning the second item in your arrays the same value over and over again...

Comment: also: `if(mean + stdDeviation <= scores[i])`. No need to repeat the opposite condition in the `else`... it is already `else`!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-declaring your variables in methods like fndMean() and fndStandard() when you do the following

```
double stdDeviation = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(25-59, 2)+(Math.pow(65-59,2))+
            (Math.pow(89-59, 2))))/3);
float mean = ((25+65+89)/3);
```

You already declare them up top and don't need to do it again, otherwise it will only set the local variables inside the methods and not inside your class. you should do

```
stdDeviation = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(25-59, 2)+(Math.pow(65-59,2))+
            (Math.pow(89-59, 2))))/3);
mean = ((25+65+89)/3);
```

Which will set those variables to what you were expecting when you call those methods **BEFORE** calculating the grades.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `fndMean` and `fndStandard` methods print:

```
 The mean is: 59.0
The Standard Deviation is: 26.407069760451147
```

Sum of `mean` and `stdDeviation` is 85.40706976045115.

Now, the condition `if(mean + stdDeviation <= scores[i])` checks whether that sum is less than equal to `score[i]` and if yes, prints 'A'. It can be true in either of these two cases:

- Values in second column (tab) in txt files are all more than 85
- `score` array gets altered between two method calls

Printing score value before those conditions should give you some more idea.

Comment: i thought that the variables and it's values local in one method can not be used in another method? thank you for your help:)